# Is there any way to delete a buffer in threejs to reduce GPU memory leak?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a very big mesh with more than 5 million triangles. I have used `BufferGeometry` with `position`, `color`, `normal`and `index` attribute. At some point, i have to remove some `indices` from the `index` attribute.

Now, i have seen that, there is no way to remove elements from the current `index` buffer. I have to create a new `BufferAttribute` and set it as `index` buffer of the geometry. But i haven't found a way to delete the previous`index` buffer which has been uploaded to GPU already. This is creating a GPU memory leak for me. I don't want to dispose the previous geometry and create a new one.

My question is - is there any way to delete the previous `index` buffer without disposing the `BufferGeometry`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can dispose of a buffer by doing:

```
BufferGeometry.dispose()
```

This will remove the object from the GPU

EDIT:

So if you read the onGeometryDispose you can come up with that answer, simply delete the attribute by calling what i suspect as a private js function but you still have access to it

Code Example:

```
if ( buffergeometry.index !== null ) {
    deleteAttribute( buffergeometry.index );

}
```

Source for answer: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/src/renderers/webgl/WebGLGeometries.js#L52-L56

Final Resolution:

Make sure to set the update flags.

http://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Updates

Comment: This is exactly what i don't want to do. Because, if i do this then i have to create a new `BufferGeometry` every time and i need to upload the `position`, `color` and `normal` data to the GPU every time. I just want to delete the current `index` buffer (GPU buffer) and create a new `index` buffer.

Comment: The following codes seem to solve the problem - 
mesh.geometry.index.array = new_indices;
mesh.geometry.index.needsUpdate = true;